# sen2cor failing with "TCI image export failed"

Tags: sentinel-2, sentinel, toa-calibration, sen2cor

I'm trying to calibrate some Sentinel L1C products to get level 2 data, but I always end up with the following message. Any idea what could cause that?

I have tested it with sen2cor 2.8.0 and sen2cor 2.9.0 with the same result. The product I'm working with is `S2B_MSIL1C_20180421T100029_N0206_R122_T33UVR_20180421T120642.SAFE` if that could be of any interest.

```
Sentinel-2 Level 2A Processor (Sen2Cor). Version: 2.8.0, created: 2019.02.20, supporting Level-1C product version 14.2 - 14.5 started ...
Product version: 14.5
Operation mode: TOOLBOX
Processing baseline: 99.99
Progress[%]:  0.00 : Generating datastrip metadata
L1C datastrip found, L2A datastrip successfully generated
Selected resolution: 10 m
Progress[%]: 0.05 : PID-10, L2A_ProcessTile: 20 m resolution must be processed first, elapsed time[s]: 1.261, total: 0:00:07.319807
Progress[%]: 0.12 : PID-10, L2A_ProcessTile: processing with resolution 20 m, elapsed time[s]: 1.571, total: 0:00:08.890806
Progress[%]: 0.12 : PID-10, L2A_ProcessTile: start of pre processing, elapsed time[s]: 0.000, total: 0:00:08.891253
Progress[%]: 0.12 : PID-10, L2A_Tables: start import, elapsed time[s]: 0.057, total: 0:00:08.948456
Progress[%]: 0.18 : PID-10, L2A_Tables: band B01 imported, elapsed time[s]: 1.522, total: 0:00:10.470635
...
Progress[%]: 50.05 : PID-10, L2A_Tables: band AOT exported, elapsed time[s]: 3.815, total: 0:20:07.139011
Progress[%]: 51.00 : PID-10, L2A_Tables: band WVP exported, elapsed time[s]: 22.923, total: 0:20:30.062450
TCI image export failed
Progress[%]: 51.34 : PID-10, L2A_Tables: TCI image export failed, elapsed time[s]: 8.100, total: 0:20:38.162143
Progress[%]: 51.34 : PID-10, L2A_Tables: stop export, elapsed time[s]: 0.073, total: 0:20:38.235323
Module L2A_T33UVR_A005868_20180421T100427 failed
Progress[%]: 100.00 : Application terminated with at least one error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was that I ran out of RAM. I would appreciate better error messages from sen2cor though, but yes, it was so simple.